# How to change the item inside the menu from span to custom div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, contextmenu

I want to replace the span in the context menu to a custom div:
This is the code used:

```
$.contextMenu({
            selector: '.context-menu-row',
            items: {
                copy: {
                    name: function(){
                        return "Layout"
                        },
                    callback: function(key, opt){
                        alert("Clicked on " + key);
                    }
                    }
                }
            });
```

So instead of "Layout" I need to put a div divided into 3 divs.

Comment: I am no expert in jQuery, but maybe you could just append them http://api.jquery.com/append/? Wrap your three divs in one div and append it wherever you want to.

Comment: JQuerycontext menu is appended onthe page when called. Not sure appending my own html to the menu everytime it's initiated is a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing an element, you can have both in the document and change their `display` property, hiding or displaying the element as you like. To hide an object, just disable the display property as follows:

```
display: none;
```

To display it again, change the display property to whatever you need to.

More information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/display